# A problem I met about ggh4x after its update from v 0.1.2.1 to v 0.2.1

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggh4x

I draw a plot using ggplot2 and ggh4x with the help from @teunbrand. And it works perfect in ggh4x old version 0.1.2.1. A key function was from the author and it helped me a lot.

But several days agao, I updated some pacages including the ggh4x and now it is v 0.2.1.

Then the plot can not be produced normally with the error:
**Error in strip$grobs[is_strip][[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031477/can-i-adjust-the-fillcolor-of-different-label-regions-when-using-ggh4x-package)] : 下标出界(subscript out of bounds)**

So I think it may work if I downgrade the  ggh4x version to the original version 0.1.2.1.

However the problem stil exists.  I haven't changed my data so I want to know if there is something wrong with the ggh4x ?

########  here is the original question:
[Can I adjust the fill(color) of different label regions when using ggh4x package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031477/can-i-adjust-the-fillcolor-of-different-label-regions-when-using-ggh4x-package)

Here is the code:

```
    data<-structure(list(Name = structure(53:68, .Label = c("1_control", 
                                                        "1_CCM(Kit1 ko)", "2_control", "2_CCM(Pdcd20 ko)", "3_control", 
                                                        "3_1 day", "3_3 days", "3_1 month", "4_control", "4_1 day", "4_3 days", 
                                                        "4_1 month", "5_control", "5_1 day", "5_3 days", "5_1 month", 
                                                        "6_control", "6_TBI(1 day)", "7_control", "7_TBI(3 day)", "8_control", 
                                                        "8_TBI(1 month)", "9_control", "9_VEGF", "10_control", "10_VEGF", 
                                                        "11_Brain Healty", "12_control_1", "12_control_2", "12_AOD(Jnk1/2/3 ko)", 
                                                        "13_control", "13_Cpt1_ko(Cdh5 driven)", "14_control", "14_Tsc2ko(Tbx4 driven)", 
                                                        "15_control", "15_Zmpste24 ko", "16_control", "16_Adrenomedullin\nko(Cdh5 driven)", 
                                                        "17_Lung Healthy", "18_control(14w)", "18_carboplatin(14w)", 
                                                        "18_radiation(14w)", "18_6 weeks", "18_70 weeks", "19_ECs(bone marrow)", 
                                                        "20_control", "20_diabetic nephropathy", "21_control", "21_Alport syndrome", 
                                                        "22_control", "22_Alport syndrome", "23_Kidney Healthy", "24_control", 
                                                        "24_Differentiated", "25_Heart Healthy", "26_control", "26_Tumor", 
                                                        "27_control", "27_Nonalcoholic\nsteatohepatitis", "28_Liver Healthy", 
                                                        "29_control", "29_autoimmune uveitis", "30_control", "30_facioscapulohumeral\nmuscular dystrophy", 
                                                        "31_control", "31_RANKL ko", "32_control", "32_Notch1  +/vg", 
                                                        "32_Notch1  +/12", "32_Notch1  +/-", "32_Notch1  -/12"), class = "factor"), 
                     Disease = structure(c(24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
                                           28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("CCM\nmodel1", 
                                                                                                    "CCM\nmodel2", "Epilepsy", "EAE", "Stroke", "TBI\n1day", 
                                                                                                    "TBI\n3day", "TBI\n1month", "VEGF\nsti_DG\nregion", "VEGF\nsti_CA1\nregion", 
                                                                                                    "Healthy\n(Brain)", "AOD", "CPT1\nko", "Tsc2\nko", "Zmpste\n_24 ko", 
                                                                                                    "AM\nko", "Healthy\n(Lung)", "Chemo\nRadio\n(Tibiae)", "ECs\n(BM)", 
                                                                                                    "diabetic\nnephro\n_pathy", "Alport\nsyndrome\nEC\npopulation1", 
                                                                                                    "Alport\nsyndrome\nEC\npopulation2", "Healthy\n(Kidney)", 
                                                                                                    "Aorta", "Healthy\n(Heart)", "Tumor", "NASH", "Healthy\n(Liver)", 
                                                                                                    "EAU", "FSHD", "RANKL\nko", "Notch1\nmodified"), class = "factor"), 
                     Organ = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
                                         8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Brain", "Lung", "Bone", 
                                                                               "Kidney", "Aorta", "Liver", "Retina", "Mus", "Lymp", "Embryo"
                                         ), class = "factor"), fill = c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFF33", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#FFFFFF", "#00F5FF", "#FFFFFF", "#00F5FF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#666666", "#FFFFFF", "#7FC97F", "#FFFFFF", "#BEAED4", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#A6D854"), Condition = c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                                                  "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", 
                                                                                                  "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#fbb03b", "#fbb03b", "#fbb03b", 
                                                                                                  "#fbb03b"), Organ_fill = c("#FFFF33", "#FFFF33", "#FFFF33", 
                                                                                                                             "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#666666", 
                                                                                                                             "#666666", "#7FC97F", "#7FC97F", "#BEAED4", "#BEAED4", "#A6D854", 
                                                                                                                             "#A6D854"), mean = c(858.98750157615, 420.38122185754, 262.590442373838, 
                                                                                                                                                  185.670810881339, 233.452076898716, 3219.28563479013, 2427.32556269574, 
                                                                                                                                                  1552.81582140235, 394.765393523994, 420.454351698853, 1295.47692129111, 
                                                                                                                                                  1357.53823242958, 1352.71703262044, 1319.89488759262, 4.78327819764262, 
                                                                                                                                                  6.86013366170554), sd = c(55.535911372066, 15.5347305073907, 
                                                                                                                                                                            29.5537795773611, 17.4390137323828, 36.0381883614951, 641.298872189499, 
                                                                                                                                                                            338.296364941458, 254.748027714364, 17.1375059099585, 100.491982520438, 
                                                                                                                                                                            49.0693043847785, 191.034062908029, 105.031407429784, 185.916546617784, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1.21846060820158, 3.38993644072368)), row.names = 53:68, class = "data.frame")
#####
g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(Name,mean, label = Name,fill=Organ)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge2", stat="identity",width = 0.85,color="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),position = position_dodge(0.85), width = .2) +
  facet_nested(.~Organ+Disease, scales="free",switch = "x",nest_line = TRUE)+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.margin = unit(c(5, 10, 10, 10), "mm"),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle=0),
    strip.placement = "outside")

# Convert to gtable
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)

assign_strip_colours <- function(gt, index, colours) {
  if (length(index) != length(colours))
    stop()
  
  # Decide which strips to recolour, here: the first 3
  is_strips <- which(startsWith(gt$layout$name, "strip-b"))[index]
  # Extract strips
  strips <- gt$grobs[is_strips]
  # Loop over strips
  strips <- mapply(function(strip, colour) {
    # Find actual strip
    is_strip <- strip$layout$name == "strip"
    grob <- strip$grobs[is_strip][[1]]
    # Find rectangle
    is_rect <- which(vapply(grob$children, inherits, logical(1), "rect"))
    # Change colour
    grob$children[[is_rect]]$gp$fill <- colour
    # Put back into strip
    strip$grobs[is_strip][[1]] <- grob
    return(strip)
  }, strip = strips, colour = colours)
  # Put strips back into gtable
  gt$grobs[is_strips] <- strips
  return(gt)
}

gt <- assign_strip_colours(gt, 1:15, rainbow(15))

# Plot gtable
grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

So I hope @teunbrand could help me. vary thankful.

Comment: @teunbrand , Sir, could you give me some advice. Thanks a lot

Comment: @teunbrand and  I have done a lot on my work, so it will be difficult for me to do some change on the newest version. For this reason, could you help sovle my problem on the old version ?

Comment: This is why one does not update packages during a project. If this error is reproducible, I think it is better to file a github issue instead, so the maintainer of the package will also be notified.

Comment: @danlooo Yeap, Sir, it is really a big trouble to me. Though I downgraded the package version, but  the problem hasn't  disappeared.

Comment: @teunbrand , Sir, I really  need your help.